# Mongoose - trying to update an object in MongoDB, getting error: "object.save is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update an object that I have in MongoDB using Mongoose, but I am getting the error `TypeError: course.save is not a function`. I can create and find the 'course' objects just fine.
I've followed instructions in the course exactly and tried to troubleshoot but to no avail!
Any idea what's going on here?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground', {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB...', err));


const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    isPublished: Boolean
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Courses', courseSchema);

async function createCourse() {
    const course = new Course({
        name: 'Course 1',
        author: 'Mosh',
        tags: ['angular', 'frontend'],
        isPublished: true
    });

    const result = await course.save(); // neccesarily async
    console.log(result);
}

// createCourse();

async function updateCourse(id) {
    const course = Course.findById(id);
    if (!course) return;
    course.isPublished = true;
    course.author = 'Another Author';    
    const result = await course.save();
    console.log(result);
}

updateCourse('5c1a528838633f2f80379061');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think it is because your find is asynchronous and you cannot using find method without a 'await' like this :

```
const course = await Course.findById(id);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually just realised this and was going to delete my question. Thanks!